# Automatic sequencing in r

Tags: r

I have a data and within that data I want to develop a model with the values selected using a sequence. In my computation,  I want `i` and `j` to be automatically change like, when the sequence under `i` changes from `seq (1, 18, 2), to seq (2, 19, 2), (3,20,2), (4, 21, 2)…..(9, 26,2)` and `j` change from `(19, 27) to (20, 27), (21, 27), (22, 27)……(27, 27)` respectively , and at the same time in the loop the argument `obs = c (i, 18)`, should be changed in to `c(i,19), c(i, 20) .....c(i, 26)` and I have tried the following but I have to change `i` and the first value of `j` manually at each step and I need your usual cooperation!

```
for (i in seq (1, 18, 2)) {
        for (j in seq (19,27)) {
      output <- arguments (…….,  obs = c (i, 18), pred = c (j, j+1))
}
}
```

But I have to change the `i` and `j` in the argument in the sequence manually, I want it to be changed automatically by r in the loop! any help, please?

Comment: Do you need a function or not?

Comment: Any possible solution, please and I wouldn't mind if you give me any alternatives! thanks!

Comment: I added a function, I specified `somefunction` for the inner command as it is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option with `Map`

```
 Map(seq, 1:9, 18:26, MoreArgs = list(by = 2))
```

---

If we want to automatically change the loop, values, then we could use a function

```
f1 <- function(input1, input2, input3, by) {
          s1 <- seq(input1, input2, by = by)
          s2 <- seq(input2 +1, input3)
          output <- c()
          for(i in s1) {
             for(j in s2) {
             output <- c(output, somefunction)
           }
          }
      }
```

and then we call it as

```
f1(1, 18, 2, 27)
```

And applying this on multiple values

```
Map(f1, 1:9, 18:26, 2, 27)
```

Comment: thank you very much and I will check it and get back to you! where do I put this one, in the argument part?

Comment: @Stackoverflowuser Your code showed is a bit unclear to me i.e. `arguments(...`.  That is the reason I didn't expand with the nested part

Comment: I can give like if I use the model output simplex, output= simplex(data[], obs=c(i, 19), pred = (j, jt1), .....), how can I automatically change the argument based on the above diescription?

Comment: @akurn, you got it right with the function, can you give me the other alternative without the function,

Comment: @Stackoverflowuser can you show a simple reproducible example for testing etc because I am not able to get the picture correctly. thanks

Comment: I will but for the time being, the concept seems working for me and if it doesn't work for me, I will organize properly the real data and get back to you, thanks..

Comment: @Stackoverflowuser thank you.  Always glad to help you.

Comment: can you help me in solving this problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62742804/pasting-the-iteration-to-the-output-in-r?noredirect=1#comment110954870_62742804