# Pasting the iteration to the output in r

Tags: r

I want to save the output of the following for loop structure in external folder including the iteration values ( i, j,  and  c) in the result so that I can recognize the combination of the iteration. I have multivariate time series data and I divided each data in to training and testing set and a single time series consists of 20 years of time series and I used 20 years to build the model and I used the remaining 10 years to predict the model and then I computed the prediction error (observed minus predicted value).  I used the second iteration (j) to move up and down in the testing set.
I have tried the following for loop structure but it hasn’t given me what I want, any help would be appreciated, including the code itself.

```
    dat <- list()
error<- NULL
for (i in 1:9) {
 for (j in 1:5) {
for (c in 1:5) {
       training_set <-0.67*data
       testing_set <-  -training
```

The output expected:

```
    i   j  c  error
    1   1   1   25
    1   1   2   26
    1   1   3   35
    1   1   4   58
    ……………………………………………
    …………………………………………….
```

data <-

```
structure(list(Plot = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),  LogCount = c(1.908485019, 
    1.653212514, 1.982271233, 1.643452676, 1.380211242, 0.903089987, 
    1.447158031, 1.505149978, 1.591064607, 1.462397998, 1.602059991, 
    1.230448921, 0.602059991, 1.079181246, 1.255272505, 1.041392685, 
    1.799340549, 1.991226076, 1.892094603, 1.880813592, 1.826074803, 
    1.556302501, 1.748188027, 1.633468456, 1.908485019, 0.903089987, 
    1.146128036, 1.301029996, 1.397940009, 1.278753601, 2.130333768,
```

Comment: What is the `dd` object?

Comment: @countorlok, I just want to predict in the new data and I divided the original data in to the one uses to build the model and to test the model (dd). thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show what your data looks like.

Comment: @countorlok, I edited my post and included data (60 obs), can you suggest me some solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The following syntax works for me dat <- rbind (dat, c(i, j, c, error))